# MYSQL, DATETIME, Events, Group by Month/Year in SQL or at output?

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp, merge, multidimensional-array

I have an events table with a `start_date` field, a standard date time. I am looking to select all the events in the table, and then output them in groups, separated by the events respective Month and year.

I am using this query:

```
SELECT Event.id, Event.name, Event.start_date, Event.end_date,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `Event`.`start_date`) AS `event_month`,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `Event`.`start_date`) AS `event_year`
FROM `my_events` AS `Event`
```

which produces the following `$events` array: (using CakePHP)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Event Name One
                    [start_date] => 2011-07-03 11:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2011-07-03 16:00:00
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event_month] => 7    // This event occurs in July
                    [event_year] => 2011
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Event Name Two   
                    [start_date] => 2011-07-09 11:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2011-07-09 15:00:00
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event_month] => 7   // this event occurs in July
                    [event_year] => 2011
                )

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Event Name Three
                    [start_date] => 2011-07-09 11:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2011-07-09 15:00:00
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [event_month] => 8   // this event occurs in august.
                    [event_year] => 2011
                )

        )
```

I am looking to now cycle through these arrays, and produce output such as:

#### July

- Event Name One
- Event Name Two

#### August

- Event Name Three

I have opted to use the `EXTRACT` SQL function as it appeared to be quite a common method of grabbing data for such a purpose.

I considered that `array_merge` might be an option, but `$result = array_merge($event)` doesn't appear to do anything.

Am I on the right lines, or would there be a better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use group by:

```
select month( event.start_date), year( event.start_date), group_concat( distinct event.name ) from my_events event group by year(event.start_date), month(event.start_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` or the `MONTHNAME()` functions but I don't think you need `GROUP BY` but `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT YEAR( Event.start_date )  AS event_year
     , MONTH( Event.start_date ) AS event_month
     , MONTHNAME( Event.start_date ) AS event_month_name
     , Event.id
     , Event.name
     , Event.start_date,
     , Event.end_date
FROM my_events AS Event
WHERE Event.start_date >= '2011-07-01'
  AND Event.start_date < '2013-01-01'
ORDER BY Event.start_date ASC
```

And you use the `event_year` and `event_month` in your PHP code to add the **July**, **August**, etc... and **2011** tags when the month or year changes from one row to the next.